# Changing the colour of an AwesomeIcon dynamically with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, font-awesome

I have this awesome Icon

```
<i id="myIdAwesomeIcon" class="fa fa-toggle-off fa-lg"  style="color:#e6e6e6;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

I've tried to change the color dynamically using

```
 $('#myIdAwesomeIcon').css("color")).val("#009900");
```

but the color didn't change

Comment: `.css('color', '#009900');`

Comment: change your code  $('#myIdAwesomeIcon').css("color")).val("#009900");
 to $('#myIdAwesomeIcon').css('color', '#009900');

Comment: This is not the correct syntax. I'd suggest you refer to the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JQuery then it should be `css("color","#009900")`:

```js
$('#myIdAwesomeIcon').css("color","#009900");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<i id="myIdAwesomeIcon" class="fa fa-toggle-off fa-lg"  style="color:#e6e6e6;" aria-hidden="true">aa</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$('#myIdAwesomeIcon').css("color","#009900");
```

[Read more about the `.css()` jQuery function.](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

> `.css( propertyName, value )`
>
> **propertyName**
>
> Type: String
>
> *A CSS property name.*
>
> **value**
>
> Type: String or Number
>
> *A value to set for the property.*